# sql injection - risk with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to read user query from variable as (:user_query:) and execute it - in Oracle it will be like:

```
DECLARE
  ddl_qry CLOB;
  user_query VARCHAR2(20) := 'SELECT 100 FROM dual';
BEGIN 
  ddl_qry := 'INSERT INTO a (v) VALUES ((SELECT CAST(( ' || user_query || ') AS NUMBER) as COUNTER FROM dual))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl_qry;
END;
```

I need to insert result of user_query to table 'a'.

I don't care if it will fail or sth, but is this safe? :) Is there any option if string user_query with SQL will drop my database or do sth else?

Comment: "I would like to read user query from TABLE as (:user_query:) and execute it as string" However, you are not reading it from a table; you are using the `DUAL` table and by prefixing it with a colon you are declaring a bind variable (the trailing colon is syntactically invalid). Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that will actually run and matches your description otherwise we are left guessing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I fixed description.

Answer (score 2):

> Or sb can construct a query that will drop my database?

If we fix the (many) syntax errors in your PL/SQL block we come to:

```sql
DECLARE
  ddl_qry CLOB;
  user_query VARCHAR2(20) := '1024';
BEGIN 
  ddl_qry := 'INSERT INTO a (v) VALUES ((SELECT CAST(( :user_query ) AS NUMBER) as COUNTER FROM dual))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl_qry USING user_query;
END;
/
```

It will work and there is not a SQL injection vulnerability as it uses a bind variable `:user_query` to input the value.

However, that does not mean that it is particularly good as you:

- Do not need to use dynamic SQL;
- Do not need to select from the `DUAL` table; and
- Do not need to explicitly `CAST` the input to a `NUMBER` as, if the column you are inserting into is a `NUMBER` then, there will be an implicit cast.

So the above code can be simplified to:

```sql
DECLARE
  user_query VARCHAR2(20) := '1024';
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO a (v) VALUES ( user_query );
END;
/
```

There is still no SQL injection vulnerability and the query is much simpler.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40c34718fb8566ca285d70ffa3a04bfd)*

---

## Update

> in Oracle it will be like:
>
> ```sql
> DECLARE
>   ddl_qry CLOB;
>   user_query VARCHAR2(20) := 'SELECT 100 FROM dual';
> BEGIN 
>   ddl_qry := 'INSERT INTO a (v) VALUES ((SELECT CAST(( ' || user_query || ') AS NUMBER) as COUNTER FROM dual))';
>   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl_qry;
> END;
> ```

That has huge SQL injection vulnerabilities.

If `user_query` is, instead, set to:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   users 
              WHERE  username = 'Admin'
              AND    password_hash = STANDARD_HASH( 'my$ecretPassw0rd', 'SHA256' )
            )
       THEN 100
       ELSE 0
       END
FROM   DUAL
```

If you get the value 100 then you know that:

- There is a table called `users`;
- It has columns `username` and `password_hash`;
- There is an `Admin` user; and
- You've verified their password.

Please don't use dynamic SQL and string concatenation if you do not need to.

Comment: I fixed description. Now should be much more clear.